# Anyway to use thread in C without pthread.h?

Tags: c, visual-studio, pthreads, windows-7-x64

My environment is Windows 7 64 bits.
The purpose is make some threads to work faster.
I have experience with thread in Linux 64(I used pthread), But Windows is first.

Now I search my computer, can not find .
So is there any other ways to use thread in C without install or download something except Visual Studio things?
Thanks.

- I do not need C++ or C# source code. it is all about C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the win32 libraries?

e.g. start with:

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  _In_opt_   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
  _In_       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_opt_   LPVOID lpParameter,
  _In_       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_opt_  LPDWORD lpThreadId
);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx for more thread related functions that you might want to use after that.

No additional libraries will be needed other than your Visual Studio tools. The exact same API also works across 32 or 64bit windows machines.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, but this is not I wanted. I guess that Windows system originally has some threading method in it. Is not it? For instance, in Ubuntu system, I can use pthread.h without installing or setting anything. Furthermore, That header has some kind of struct in it, so I just make thread like 'pthread_t a;'. That way is what I wanted. Is it impossible in Windows?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh Everything you can do with posix threads you will be able to do using win32 threads. The API will naturally be a little different to what you're used to - but not a huge architectural difference. If you need a consistent API across both Windows and Linux you'll have to write (or find) some wrapper code to handle both threading libraries. C++11 introduces this for example.

Comment: Thanks. I just did not understand how the environment is important at that time. I always want to use some code which runs in cross-environments. but now I understand that sometimes have to use some other libraries. Choosing right library is also one of the important things to write a code. Thank even though the question is quite over time.